# Is there a way to store and apply html content to a page like how CSS stores and applies styles

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to html and CSS, been learning on the go to update a website.

I understand how you can use CSS to store styles so that you can apply styles to multiple elements/pages with ease, and changing the attributes in a CSS style will automatically change all the html styles it governs across multiple pages.

I was wondering if you are able to do this somehow with actual html content instead of just style attributes.

Example: We have heaps of project pages, at the end of every project page we have a table with a bio of the manager who ran the project.  This html code is manually written into every page.  Since it is manually written though, if you ever want to change or update the info in bio table, you will have to go through and manually update it on every page.  Is there a way to have the info in the bio table stored in something similar to a CSS stylesheet, so it just links to every page, and updating the info in the stylesheet will automatically update the info on every page it is linked in.

Code something like:
CSS

```
.personAbio {
<table><tr><td>Name</td>
<td>Sales Last Week</td></tr>
<tr><td>John</td>
<td>$100</td></tr>
</table>
}
```

Html

```
<table class="personAbio">
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to accomplish what you need.

#### Statically include content

The first way is by using (as already suggested) some **server-side** language.
**Using PHP** it's simple as, say we're inside your `project_8.php` (**notice the PHP extension!**) you simply place this PHP code where you want the about content to appear:

```
<?php include "about.html"; ?>
```

#### Dynamically include content

There's also a **dynamic** way to accomplish the same using **JavaScript** and AJAX.
For sake of simplicity hers's how it's done using the **jQuery library**:

```html
<div id="hereGoesTheAbout"></div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#hereGoesTheAbout").load("about.html");
</script>
```

The above two `<script>` tags are best placed right **before** the closing `</body>` tag.
Including content dynamically is crawlable by Googlebot, just, a small penalty is given (over the static implementation) - since the additional requests to retrieve the content.

---

The difference is that using a **server-side** technique the content is found and embedded into a page while still on the server.

Using **JavaScript** and **AJAX** (like in the example above) the page arrives to your browser and than JavaScript dynamically sends to the server a request for the desired content to include.

---

Not a good way to insert content is by using `<iframe>`.  It's terribly complicated (and involves lot of JS and `messaging` techniques) to make it responsive.
Also search engines will not index such content so it's not good for your page SEO.

---

#### Winner

**Static include**. Using the same technique you can split your website architecture into manageable ***includes***.

Say you have some `product.php` **template** page, and you have all your products inside a folder `products/` as files like `000.html` to `999.html`.
By just linking to `example.com/product.php?pr=233` you can get your `233.html` product:

```
<?php include "header.html"; ?>

<article>
   <h2>Product:</h2>
   <?php include "products/{$_GET['pr']}.html"; ?>
</article>

<aside>
   <?php include "about.html"; ?>
</aside>

<?php include "footer.html"; ?>
```

with the above what you have:

- one `product.php` file **template** (for all your products)
- only one `header.html` file
- only one `footer.html` file
- only one *author* file
- one `products/` folder with all your `nnn.html` products contents.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a back end coding language like PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Do you know a branch or specific command of PHP I could search for to learn about how to do this?

Comment: I would start with a basic php tutorial...  what you are looking to do sounds like build dynamic content. You could start there.

Comment: W3schools has great tutorials for free: https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

But you can use JavaScript instead to store your data and then bind them into the table.

For exemple:

html:

```
<table class="personaBio">
    <thead>
        <tr>Name<\tr>
        <tr>Sale of the last week</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript/JQuery

```
var persons = [{name:'John', saleLastWeek:'100'}];
persons.forEach(function(person) {
    $('tbody').append(`<tr><td>${person.name}</td><td>${person.saleLastWeek}</td></tr>`);
}
```

This is an exemple, I am on my phone, I didn't try this code.
You need to learn JavaScript or Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can do it server-side, using a number of approaches:

- [Server-side includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)
- Any server-side language/frameworks: PHP, Ruby, Python, Java, etc.

You can, however, also do it on the client side:

- With `<iframe>`: `<iframe src="managers/john.html">`
- With Javascript:

  1. Put all manager bios into, say, `manager-bios.js`:

     ```
     var managerBios = { 
       "john" : { "fullName": "John Doe", "projects": ["a", "b", "c"] ...}
       "jane" : ....
     }
     ```
  2. Reference it in the html: `<script src="manager-bios.js"`
  3. Reference corresponding manager on the page: `<div id="responsibleManager" data-manager="john">`
  4. On page load, populate manager's data (I'm using jQuery here):

     ```
     $(document).load(function() {
        var managerId = $("#responsibleManager").data("manager");
        $("#responsibleManager").html("<div>" + managerBios[managerId].fullName + "</div> Projects: " + managerBios[managerId].projects.join(","));
     }
     ```
- Load data from external source with Javascript (again, using jQuery here, assuming same html as above):

  ```
  $("#responsibleManager").load("managers/" + $("#responsibleManager").data("manager") + ".html");
  ```